# 3xAA Battery Pack how to wire?

Tags: batteries, charger

I've mistakenly purchase an unwired battery pack, I'm unsure about how to wire this, never done anything like this but I thought if try and understand wiring a bit better. I have a 3xAA battery pack that I bought from Maplin but I don't know how to wire it, all the tutorials I see already has the wires protruding from it. Sorry for the basic question

Comment: A link to what you have would be helpful. We aren't psychic and there are an awful lot of different battery packs in different shapes and sizes.

Comment: Sorry it's this one exactly http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/3-aa-battery-box-yr61r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link to the battery pack you have, it seems that it is designed to be connected using a PP3 style battery snap:

[image: Battery Pac Connector]

Essentially you need something like [this](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/pp3-snap-battery-clip-hf28f):

[image: PP3 Battery Snap]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the answer to my question, I appreciate the help

Comment: @AndreQueen If it answers your question, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the tick mark in the top left corner of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tom has kindly explained what you need. Just to help you using the Maplin website in future, notice that on each product page, is a tab called "Questions". There, you can ask your own question to Maplin staff or read previous questions & their answers. If you do that, you will see that this question has already been answered on the "Questions" tab at [the web page you linked](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/3-aa-battery-box-yr61r):

---

[image: Maplin product YR61R question tab]

---

It also mentions that the connection is a "PP3 clip" near the bottom of the normal "Overview" tab on that page:

---

[image: Maplin product YR61R overview tab]

---

Hopefully that will give you some pointers for the future.

Comment: And thank you for the insight into the maplin website, very useful! Appreciate it, thanks